# Ubuntu 20.04 tab flashing screen after upgrading from 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, upgrade, 20.04, login-screen

I am having Lenovo G40-80 laptop with configuration of i3-5th gen processor

I recently upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 LTS from ubuntu 18.04. After doing all the necessary steps and restarting the system, just after the ubuntu loading screen a blank screen appears with tab flashing in the top left corner, and nothing coming ahead. Infact in recovery mode too of other kernel versions. I am not able to get account screen.

The screen remains the same until forcefully shutting it down.

I tried some remedies but nothing helps.

Can someone please help?
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting gdm3 worked for me in ubuntu cli!
First check your gdm3 status by typing

```
sudo systemctl status gdm3
```

After entering see whether all parameters are proper and are running or not. In my case some parameter failed to run. So I restarted gdm3 by entering the command

```
sudo systemctl restart gdm3
```

This worked for me. Hope it helps others.